# How can I configure MS Edge browser in a corporate domain account to sync "Favorites" with a non-domain MS-linked consumer account?

Tags: windows-10, office365, microsoft-edge, azure-activedirectory

How can I run the Microsoft Edge web browser from within a Windows 10 account on a PC belonging to a corporate domain in such a manner that Edge in the corporate account syncs its "Favorites," "Reading List," and "Set Aside" tabs with other Edge installations on devices in accounts linked only to a private consumer Microsoft Account?

The corporation uses Microsoft Office 365 cloud services (all employees use MS OneDrive and the MS Office 365 suite), Active Directory, and authenticates users of those services via a corporate portal. Also, simply being "logged in" to a personal Microsoft Account in Edge within the Windows 10 corporate domain account does NOT result in syncing of content.

In the case in point, the corporate domain and MS-linked consumer accounts are all running Version 1803 of Windows 10. In Version 1703, the syncing seemed to have occurred as desired.

Thanks!

Comment: What you want isn’t possible.  The syncing happens would you link a profile to a MS account which cannot be done in your case

Comment: First of all, welcome to Super User!  Unfortunately, I doubt that what you want is actually possible, but hopefully someone else will chime in and prove me wrong.  That being said, a question of this nature might find a better target audience within the [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) community.  However, on my primary work domain I utilize Firefox Sync within Mozilla's web browser to essentially achieve the same goals.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is a way to do this via a free 3rd-party application called EdgeSync.  It is a replacement for the built-in sync system, where you have complete control on where the "master" copy is stored (in the cloud, network folder, usb flash drive, etc).  And you can control the frequency of syncs via a Scheduled task...or just sync manually whenever you think about it.

Take a look at this article to see if this is something that you'd be interested in: http://www.edgemanage.emmet-gray.com/Articles/EdgeSync.html